# HTML - Set list items based on listbox selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have data which looks roughly like this:

```
[{
    "CountryName" : "Australia",
    "FinanceTypes" : [{
            "Name" : "Hire",
            "AccountTypes" : ["Account 1", "Account 2", "Account 3",]
        }, {
            "Name" : "Lease",
            "AccountTypes" : ["Account 4", "Account 5", "Account 6",]
        }
    ]
},{
    "CountryName" : "USA",
    "FinanceTypes" : [{
            "Name" : "Hire",
            "AccountTypes" : ["Account 7", "Account 8", "Account 9",]
        }, {
            "Name" : "Lease",
            "AccountTypes" : ["Account 10", "Account 11", "Account 12",]
        }
    ]
}]
```

To display this, I want each country to be a row in a table, and have 2 lists in the row - one for financetype and one for accounttype. The values in the AccountType list will be based on the selection in the FinanceType list.

I would like to avoid ajax calls as I can get all the data when the page loads. What's the best way to do this ? Do I put all the data into a javascript array when the page is rendered and add listeners to each of the financetype lists?

Thanks

Comment: Are you building the table dynamically based on this data? and are `FinanceTypes` always 'Hire' and 'Lease' or do they vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a framework for something like this. You could of course do this using jQuery (or even pure JS!), but it will quickly grow into an unscalable mess.

Which framework should you use? That's up to you! Based solely on what I've seen here, I would suggest something lightweight, such as [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/). The main feature you need is data-binding. If your app needs more features such as routing and modularity, I would suggest you take a look at [Angularjs](http://www.angularjs.org).